# including XSL template and merge output

Tags: xml, xslt

I have 2 xsl stylesheets, which both transform the element `<Group id="all">`:

The output should be merged, but instead is being overridden by `main.xslt` or `include.xslt`. (depending on the order)

I'd prefer to not modify the `include.xslt` file, as it is shared among other stylesheets, which should not be modified.

main.xslt

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:include href="include.xslt"/>
  <xsl:template match="Group[@id='all']">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="@*|node()" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="document('part1.xml')" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

include.xslt

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:template match="Group[@id='all']">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="@*|node()" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="document('part2.xml')" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

input.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<Group id="all">
testdata below:
</Group>
```

part1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data id="test1">
Here is some test data.
</data>
```

part2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data id="test2">
Here is some more data.
</data>
```

Actual output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Group id="all">
testdata below:

Here is some test data.
</Group>
```

Expected output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Group id="all">
testdata below:

Here is some test data.
Here is some more data.
</Group>
```

Answer (score 0):

The normal way to do this is to use `xsl:import` instead of `xsl:include` and then add an `xsl:apply-imports`...

**main.xslt**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:import href="include.xslt"/>
  <xsl:template match="Group[@id='all']">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="@*|node()" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="document('part1.xml')" />
      <xsl:apply-imports/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

However, what you'll end up with is two `Group` elements, one nested inside the other (you could move the `xsl:apply-imports` after the `xsl:copy` to get them one after the other)...

```
<Group id="all">
testdata below:

Here is some test data.
<Group id="all">
testdata below:

Here is some more data.
</Group></Group>
```

So from what I can see you'd either need to (choose one):

- Process the output a second time to do the actual merge of the two `Group` elements.
- Use an extension function like [`node-set()`](http://exslt.org/exsl/functions/node-set/) (or use XSLT 2.0) to save the `Group` structure in a variable and then process the variable to merge the `Group`s.
- Modify `include.xslt` so it doesn't output `Group` (or the text `testdata below:`).

Comment: thanks for your answer, unfortunately, using import would not work, as there are also other templates in the included file, which would then all need to be specified in `main.xslt`. Do you have an example using node-set()?

Comment: I solved it using a node-set and will post the solution later